# Function not outputting value?

Tags: powershell

I'm working on a PowerShell script for some work use, and am having trouble getting a function it's data directly to a variable. Below is the function and my test:

```
function validateInput {
    Param(
        [string]$Text = 'Put text here'
    )

    do {
        try {
            $numOk = $true
            $GetMyANumber = Read-Host "$text"

            if ($GetMyANumber -gt 3){
                $numOK = $false
            }
        } catch {
            $numOK = $false
        }
        if ($numOK -ne $true) {
            cls
            Write-Host "Please enter a valid number" -Foreground Red
        }
    } until (($GetMyANumber -ge 0 -and $GetMyANumber -le 3) -and $numOK)
}  

$firstName = validateInput($firstNamePrompt)
$lastName = validateInput ($lastNamePrompt)

Write-Host "First name length is $firstname"
Write-Host "Last name length is $lastname"
```

My understanding is that the in the last few lines, the function SHOULD assign it's output to the variables `$firstName` and `$lastName`, but I output that, they are blank. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but can anyone let me know what I'm screwing up?

Comment: Yes, the two assignments should assign the function output to the variables. ***IF*** the function returned any output in the first place. Which it doesn't. Add `return $numOK` or just `$numOK` after the loop and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Jeez, that was dumb. I don't want to return $numOK (Wanted $GetANumber), but your answer is still right. Guess I just forgot my return line. Thanks!